# Java oracle api - how to use the abstract function : getSystemClipboard()

Tags: java

I'm reading the getSystemClipboard() function found in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/, under clipboard.

This function is declared abstract. How can I then use it ? Am i suppose to subclass it or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tookit is an abstract class. But subclasses exist that extend this abstract class and implement its abstract methods. And you can get an instance of one of those sublclasses (the one for your OS) using the static factory method Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit():

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
```

Comment: But Toolkit is abstract, so you can still set it to something ? I thought the only way to use abstract classes is by subclasses

Comment: The `getDefaultToolkit()` method, on Windows, does something like `return new WindowsToolkit()`, where `WindowsToolkit` extends `Toolkit`.

Comment: That I get - " return new WindowToolKit()". But, I didn't think you could assign it to "Toolkit toolkit" since Toolkit is abstract by definition.

Comment: Oh ok, is it because Toolkit is a valid type nonetheless...i didn't think you could do it. Because you can't do Object a = new Car(). Because Object is abstract.

Comment: A class is a class, and it defines a type. Whether it's abstract or not doesn't matter. The whole point of polymorphism is that, if an object has a given type, then it implements the methods defined in that type. You don't need to know the concrete type of the object to use it. That's why you can use Lists, Sets, Iterators, etc. although they're interfaces (i.e. purely abstract types).

Answer (score 0):

Get an instance of Toolkit

> public abstract class Toolkit extends Object
>
> This class is the abstract superclass of all actual implementations of
>   the Abstract Window Toolkit. Subclasses of the Toolkit class are used
>   to bind the various components to particular native toolkit
>   implementations. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html

Then call getSystemClipboard()

> Gets the singleton instance of the system Clipboard which interfaces
>   with clipboard facilities provided by the native platform. This
>   clipboard enables data transfer between Java programs and native
>   applications which use native clipboard facilities.

That gives you a Clipboard objetc, more information in the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html